# Texreg table does not fit on one page

Tags: r, latex, regression, texreg

I have a texreg (Latex table) that won't fit on one page. How to fit in in single page?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(texreg)

d <- mtcars %>% mutate_at(.vars=c('vs','am','gear','carb'), .funs=factor)

lm <- lm(hp~am*gear*carb*mpg*hp,data=d)

texreg(lm,file='texfile.tex',return.string=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaoround inspired by [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13812/244928):

In the beginning of the Latex-document, write `\usepackage{adjustbox}`. Thereafter, change the texreg output as follows:

```
tr <- texreg(lm,return.string=T)

tr <- gsub("\\begin{tabular}"
           ,"\\begin{adjustbox}{totalheight=\\textheight-2\\baselineskip}\n\\begin{tabular}"
           ,tr
           ,fixed=T)

tr <- gsub("\\end{tabular}"
           ,"\\end{tabular}\n\\end{adjustbox}"
           ,tr
           ,fixed=T)

write_file(tr, 'test.tex')
```

Now when you write `\input{test.tex}` in your Latex-file, the output table will be squeezed to fit one page.

Comment: From the tex perspective, it would be better to use a suitable font size instead of scaling, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for more information

Comment: is there an automatized way of making sure the table fits to one page by reducing file size? Or is it trial and error?

Comment: Trial and error. but the result will be better